# How to parallellize tasks given on the command line

Tags: sbt

I'd like to be able to execute dynamically some tasks in SBT.

So, I'm using the command line:

```
sbt taskA taskB taskC
```

It works ok, but all of them are executed sequentially.

On the other hand, if I programmatically write this inside `build.sbt`:

```
val allTasks = taskKey[Unit]("All")
allTasks := {
  taskA.value
  taskB.value
  taskC.value
}
```

all of them are executed in parallel.

How can I get this behavior on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `all` command:

**build.sbt**

```
TaskKey[String]("taskA") := { println("A start"); Thread.sleep(3000); println("A end"); "a" }
TaskKey[String]("taskB") := { println("B start"); Thread.sleep(2000); println("B end"); "b" }
TaskKey[String]("taskC") := { println("C start"); Thread.sleep(1000); println("C end"); "c" }
```

And running it:

```
> all taskA taskB taskC
C start
A start
B start
C end
B end
A end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible from the command line.

One thing that you can do from the sbt shell is define a task on the fly then run it:

```
$ set TaskKey[Unit]("allTasks") := { val a = taskA.value ; val b = taskB.value ; val c = taskC.value ; () }
[info] Defining *:allTasks

$ allTasks
[info] Running Task A in parallel
[info] Running Task B in parallel
[info] Running Task C in parallel
```

Comment: Like we have ";" for concatenating tasks sequentially, we could also have another symbol for parallel execution.

Comment: Interesting idea. Open an issue perhaps, see what the core devs think.